# Firefox/chrome work only If I am connected to VPN (private intrenet access)

Tags: networking, firefox, google-chrome, internet, vpn

I have got an strange problem. Some times when I wish to hide my ip O connect to VPN server.
Now suddenly, neither Firefox or chrome work if am not connected to VPN server.
I get a message : Problem loading Page
Server not found

Firefox can’t find the server at www.google.se.

```
Check the address for typing errors such as ww.example.com instead of www.example.com
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

as soon as I connect to VPN server every thing is OK.
It would be great if someone could help me fix this

Comment: I forgot to mention that transmission torrent client works with or without vpn and is not effected by this problem.

Comment: Please add the output of `ping -c 1 google.com` to your answer so we know whether it's a DNS problem.

Comment: I dont get result  when I write 'nslookup google.com' but when I write 'nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8'  I get 'Server:  8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: goolge.com
Address: 216.58.212.164 '

Comment: I believe this is problem with DNS but I dont know how to fix it

Comment: That's exactly what the output should be. DNS works. Does `cd /tmp && wget stackexchange.com` download the `index.html` of StackExchange? You can view the file in Firefox via `firefox "file:///tmp/index.html"`.

Comment: what's in your `cat /etc/resolv.conf`